# Use FFmpeg to combine fdshow audio capture with still image

Tags: image, audio, ffmpeg, capture

On windows I am trying to capture direct show audio and combine with a still image. I have come up with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow  -i audio="Microphone (Conexant SmartAudio HD)" -loop 1 -i black2.png -b:a 30k -ac 1 -acodec libfdk_aac -vcodec libx264 -b:v 60k -shortest test.mp4
```

This nearly works, a video with image and audio are produced but the video output is created at a much faster rate that the captured audio. So if the audio is capturing for 1 minute a 5 minute video is produced instead of 1 minute. The audio plays for the 1st minute and there is no audio for the remaining 4 minutes, The images displays through out video. 
Any help appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ffmpeg -f dshow  -i audio="Microphone (Conexant SmartAudio HD)" -loop 1 -re -i black2.png -b:a 30k -ac 1 -acodec libfdk_aac -vcodec libx264 -b:v 60k -shortest test.mp4
```

The `-re` limits the speed at which Ffmpeg processes the video - to realtime.